# Preserve variable in cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

I want to access variables in difference Given/Then/When clauses. How to preserve variables so that they are accessible everywhere?

```
Given(#something) do
  foo = 123 # I want to preserve foo
end

Then(#something) do
  # how to access foo at this point??? 
end
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To share variables across step definitions, you need to use instance or global variables.

Instance variables can be used when you need to share data across step definitions but only for the one test (ie the variables are cleared after each scenario). Instance variables start with a @.

```
Given(#something) do
  @foo = 123
end

Then(#something) do
  p @foo
  #=> 123
end
```

If you want to share a variable across all scenarios, you could use a global variable, which start with a $.

```
Given(#something) do
  $foo = 123
end

Then(#something) do
  p $foo
  #=> 123
end
```

Note: It is usually recommended not to share variables between steps/scenarios as it creates coupling.

Comment: I recommend defaults `@foo ||= :bar` where it's possible so that the step could be used without the other step.