# RSpec - Using `let` in spec helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a large model that takes time to initialize in my RSpec tests.

I want it potentially available to every example, but want to only load it if an example requires it.

This seems like the perfect use for `let()`'s lazy loading - only load it when you need it.

In any particular spec file I can do

```
require "spec_helper"

feature "foo" do
  let(:big_class) { MyBigClass.new(bar) }

  ...
end
```

This will make `big_class` available to every example in that spec file.

Is there a way to make this more global so that EVERY spec file and example can use it? I couldn't find a good way to initialize `let` inside the spec helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider other approaches:

- Use mock objects instead of real ones.
- Refactor the initializer and extract the slow operation to another method

Mock objects of course bring their own set of drawbacks; they can become stale and make tests more brittle. But for some tests that is not an issue.

Refactoring initializers is a favorite of mine. E.g.

```
MyBigObject.new(args)
```

becomes

```
MyBigObject.new(args).setup
```

or `:load_data` or `:connect_to_database_on_the_moon` or whatever is taking a long time. You get the picture.

Obviously this means changing your code, but I find that often works out to be helpful in other ways, and it certainly makes testing easier.

Answer (score 5):

You may simply define a [shared context](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context) and include it in every example.  Regarding your particular question, it should look like following:

```
RSpec.shared_context "Global helpers" do
  let(:big_class) { MyBigClass.new(bar) }
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include_context "Global helpers"
end
```

However, it's rarely a good idea to include a shared context in *all* examples, and that `big_class` helper from your question really looks like something domain-specific.  You can steer the shared context inclusion by metadata, for example when you want to include given shared context in feature specs only (they all have `:type => :feature` metadata set by default), you can do it this way:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include_context "Feature spec helpers", :type => :feature
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `let`. From the docs:

> Use let to define a memoized helper method. The value will be cached across
>   multiple calls in the same example **but not across examples**.

You'll end up instantiating MyBigClass lots of times.  I would recommend creating a global helper method somewhere in spec_helper.rb (or similar) that used memo-ization on it's own to return the cached value if it's already been setup.

Also be very careful with all this as you're violating the rule of isolated tests. Might be fine for what you're doing, but it's a red flag.

Comment: Well I'd actually like behavior `let()` provides. I don't want caching across examples - each example should run it again, if necessary (i.e. lazily). Good point on the helper method that memoizes separately, was just wondering if there was a built-in way to just define a `let()` at the highest level of specs (i.e. in the spec_helper)

Answer (score -1):

Use global before hook with an instance variable

From the [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration):

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.before(:example) {  @big_class = MyBigClass.new(bar) }
end

RSpec.describe MyExample do
  it { expect(@big_class).to eql(MyBigClass.new(bar)) } # This code will pass
end
```

For more details check the suggestions in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167031/how-to-define-a-simple-global-variable-in-an-rspec-test-that-can-be-accesed-by-h)

Comment: True, but this initializes it before every example, whether it's required or not. It's not lazy-loaded like `let()`

Comment: Why is lazy loading affecting the time of your object setup, are you calling associations or forcing eager loading ? if the object is that big might be a better solution to mock its behavior.