# define global variable in rspec for all controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe Api::V1::SessionsController, :type => :controller do

  before do 
   post :create, {email: "raj@gmail.com", user_name: "raj",password: "raj"}
   body = JSON.parse(response.body)
   @session_token = body["session_token"]
  end
end
```

I added new conroller

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe Api::V1::ProductsController, :type => :controller do
  describe "GET #index" do
    it "should list all products" do
        request.env['HTTP_SESSIONTOKEN'] = @session_token
    end
  end
end
```

Now here I want to use session_token in products_controller_spec. How do I define session_token variable.

Comment: Duplicate the code or define [Helper Methods](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module). You should always have in mind that the specs should be easy to understand. As soon as your codebase grows it will be impossible to maintain such specs. In specs it isn't bad practice to duplicate code for keeping readability.

Comment: I'll politely disagree with Tobias here, in my opinion you should not duplicate the session initialization code all over your test suite. Should that code ever change, it is not very fun to find and adjust all occurrences. The best way would probably be to use a helper method just as he said (something like authenticate_user(user)) and define that logic once and only once in a place you can find easily.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30696771/740004